# Rails bypass: true with active_for_authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4.2.3, Devise 3.5.2, and Warden 1.2.3. Modules enabled: `:database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable`

I think this might be a bug, but I'm not sure. I'm attempting to log in as a user that is disabled (via `active_for_authentication?` in my `User` model by using

```
sign_in(@user, bypass: true)
```

however it seems that active_for_authentication? is still being called even though (I think) [this callback](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/1a0192201b317d3f1bac88f5c5b4926d527b1b39/lib/devise/hooks/activatable.rb) is supposed to be skipped.

I'm hardcoding `false` and `true` into the `active_for_authentication?` method in the `User` model:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  false
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution  ?